# Cocoa: Simulate Macbook upper keys & Multimedia keys

Tags: macos, cocoa, events, simulate

I am trying to simulate the upper Macbook keys to any active app using

```
CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)keycode, true);
CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)keycode, false);
```

So far I found and sent the first 4 key's events succesfully:

```
keycode / Key

107 - Brightness Down
113 - Brightness Up
130 - Mission Control / Expose
160 - Dashboard / Launchpad
 ?? - Keyboard lit Down
 ?? - Keyboard lit Up
 ?? - Previous Track
 ?? - Play/Pause
 ?? - Next Track
 ?? - Mute
 ?? - Volume Down
 ?? - Volume Up
 ?? - Eject
```

But I can't find any of the other key codes.
I even iterate through 1000 integer sending its numbers as events, no one seems to work =P

**So, is there any way to simulate these events?**

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Media keys are not treated as normal keyboard events, for some reason. [This post](http://rogueamoeba.com/utm/2007/09/29/) shows what the events look like.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me directions. After tweaking a bit, I worked!

Answer (score 3):

As of 2017/2018 some of the APIs have changed. Try this snippet in Swift:

```
// Simulate illumination up
let code = NX_KEYTYPE_ILLUMINATION_UP
let event1 = NSEvent.otherEvent(with: .systemDefined, location: NSPoint.zero, modifierFlags: NSEventModifierFlags(rawValue: 0xa00), timestamp: 0, windowNumber: 0, context: nil, subtype: 8, data1: (Int((code << 16 as Int32) | (0xa << 8 as Int32))), data2: -1)
event1?.cgEvent?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
let event2 = NSEvent.otherEvent(with: .systemDefined, location: NSPoint.zero, modifierFlags: NSEventModifierFlags(rawValue: 0xb00), timestamp: 0, windowNumber: 0, context: nil, subtype: 8, data1: (Int((code << 16 as Int32) | (0xb << 8 as Int32))), data2: -1)
event2?.cgEvent?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)



// Simulate illumination down
let code = NX_KEYTYPE_ILLUMINATION_DOWN
let event1 = NSEvent.otherEvent(with: .systemDefined, location: NSPoint.zero, modifierFlags: NSEventModifierFlags(rawValue: 0xa00), timestamp: 0, windowNumber: 0, context: nil, subtype: 8, data1: (Int((code << 16 as Int32) | (0xa << 8 as Int32))), data2: -1)
event1?.cgEvent?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
let event2 = NSEvent.otherEvent(with: .systemDefined, location: NSPoint.zero, modifierFlags: NSEventModifierFlags(rawValue: 0xb00), timestamp: 0, windowNumber: 0, context: nil, subtype: 8, data1: (Int((code << 16 as Int32) | (0xb << 8 as Int32))), data2: -1)
event2?.cgEvent?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
```

(credit goes to [@Alex293](https://github.com/Alex293))

This is from our [discussion](https://github.com/pirate/mac-keyboard-brightness/issues/1) on ways to programmatically control the keyboard brightness with: https://github.com/pirate/mac-keyboard-brightness

Also this SO answer: [How to simulate mac media keys in cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470235/how-to-simulate-mac-media-keys-in-cocoa/50574142#50574142)