# How to simulate mac media keys in cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I need simulate the pressing of the media/function keys on the mac keyboard. Everything from  brightness to volume up/down.

Is this possible? And if so how? Ive read a bunch about how to trigger on their press, but not this.

If possible, id like the translucent icons to still come up on the screen as you change things.

Comment: I ask this question: Why? Why trigger the keypresses instead of using events and such? Similar to this with brightness: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239749/programmatically-change-mac-display-brightness

Comment: I would like, if possible to have the brightness icon come up when triggered like it does when a user presses the brightness button. I have it it in code just as it is in that answer and the icon does not come up.

Comment: I see, then may I suggest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459085/cocoa-simulate-macbook-upper-keys-multimedia-keys which will lead you here: http://weblog.rogueamoeba.com/2007/09/29/ . Don't know if it will help but it may put you on track.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out in Swift:

```
// Simulate illumination up
let code = NX_KEYTYPE_ILLUMINATION_UP
let event1 = NSEvent.otherEvent(with: .systemDefined, location: NSPoint.zero, modifierFlags: NSEventModifierFlags(rawValue: 0xa00), timestamp: 0, windowNumber: 0, context: nil, subtype: 8, data1: (Int((code << 16 as Int32) | (0xa << 8 as Int32))), data2: -1)
event1?.cgEvent?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
let event2 = NSEvent.otherEvent(with: .systemDefined, location: NSPoint.zero, modifierFlags: NSEventModifierFlags(rawValue: 0xb00), timestamp: 0, windowNumber: 0, context: nil, subtype: 8, data1: (Int((code << 16 as Int32) | (0xb << 8 as Int32))), data2: -1)
event2?.cgEvent?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)



// Simulate illumination down
let code = NX_KEYTYPE_ILLUMINATION_DOWN
let event1 = NSEvent.otherEvent(with: .systemDefined, location: NSPoint.zero, modifierFlags: NSEventModifierFlags(rawValue: 0xa00), timestamp: 0, windowNumber: 0, context: nil, subtype: 8, data1: (Int((code << 16 as Int32) | (0xa << 8 as Int32))), data2: -1)
event1?.cgEvent?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
let event2 = NSEvent.otherEvent(with: .systemDefined, location: NSPoint.zero, modifierFlags: NSEventModifierFlags(rawValue: 0xb00), timestamp: 0, windowNumber: 0, context: nil, subtype: 8, data1: (Int((code << 16 as Int32) | (0xb << 8 as Int32))), data2: -1)
event2?.cgEvent?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
```

(credit goes to [@Alex293](https://github.com/Alex293))

This is from our [discussion](https://github.com/pirate/mac-keyboard-brightness/issues/1) on ways to programmatically control the keyboard brightness with: https://github.com/pirate/mac-keyboard-brightness